# Google Sheets Formula color cell based on another cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to format a cell D2 based on text in C2. I would like C2 to be colored Red if D2 contains text.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
=C2<>""
```

[image]